# Need to pre-process input to functions

Tags: r, functional-programming

I am writing a package with a suite of functions that take objects fit to a model (e.g., output from from "lmt", "lavaan", or "mirt" packages) and computes relevant indices based on those models.

The first thing EVERY function in this suite does is convert the input into a standardized form, so all of my functions look like this:

```
fooIndex <- function(x) {
  x <- standardizerFunction(x)
  # Now, compute the fooIndex
}
```

Here, standardizerFunction is an S3 generic function that has methods for all the supported input classes.

Is there a better way to accomplish this functionality than calling standardizerFunction inside of each of the functions computing indices?

EDIT: I just wanted to specify that my "problem" is that copying and pasting the same line of code into ~20 different functions seems like a poor programming style, and I am hoping for a better solution.

Comment: You could define a new class for standardized format, and then run `if(!class(x)==YourClass) x<-standardizerFunction(x)` (you'll also have to add `class(x)<-"YourClass"` to your standardizerFucntion, of course). This way, if the information passed to a function has already been standardized, your function will skip that step. Of course, if there's a way to identify standardized data through other means, that's also an option.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful (saves me from evaluating standardizerFunction more times than I need to), but my overall concern is that I have copy/pasted the same line of code into 20 different functions, and that doesn't seem like good form.

Comment: I'm trying to think of other R packages that do something similar. `data.table` offloads the issue to the user - the user converts a data.frame to a data.table before any of the data.table functions will work. `dplyr` converts data frames to tibbles, but only as necessary (`mutate` or `summarize`, e.g., will return data frames or tibbles depending on what is passed in. `group_by` always returns a (grouped) tibble)...

Comment: Since your functions *all* need the same standardized input (like data.table, unlike dplyr where some functions work fine on unstandardized input), I think you should take the data.table approach: export `standardizeFunction`, change the class of the object so you can tell it's been standardized (extending it's current class), and make the user do it. Have your other functions throw an error if the input hasn't been standardized.

Comment: At the very least, each function has to check the class of the data passed to it to make sure it's the right one (or throw an error). I'm in favour of the dplyr way, rather than the data.table way (as per @Gregor) - but whichever way you go, you'll have to start your functions with the same line of code that checks the class of your argument (and possibly coerces it into your class). I don't think there's a way around it, and I'm quite certain it's standard practice to have this class-checking code anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it depends mostly on use-case. If you imagine a user wanting to run multiple functions on their model, it might make sense for them to do the conversion. Or if a custom print or plot method for the standardized model would be useful. If, however, a typical user might just want to run one of several possible functions, it's a better user experience to just have the function do the conversion.

Comment: Two corrections to my initial comment, however, if you're going to change the class, be sure to do it by way of `class(x)<-c("YourClass",class(x))`, so that the data inherits the class of the original dataset, and continues to use any methods associated with it. For the `if` statement, use `if(!inherits(x, what="YourClass"))`, for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks guys! I will combine your advices into an answer later this evening. My users do not like the idea of having to call the pre-processing function themselves. The typical use case is calling one or two of the functions (which may in turn call many of the others), so iod's suggestion is pretty efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what iod and Gregor wrote, the two ways to handle this are:

(1) Require the user to apply the standardizerFunction before running any of the main functions. The functions will the throw an error if the input is of the wrong class.

(2) Since our functions will be checking the input to make sure it is of the right class anyway, just fold standardizerFunction into the input checking part using something like:

```
if(!inherits(x, what="YourClass")) standardizerFunction(x)
```

In my particular setting, since most of my users are uncomfortable with R, asking them to pre-apply the standardizerFunction is not the best choice, so I am going with option 2.